# Make Virtualhost detect Wildcard with and without preceding www

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

In my Apache (Xampp) `httpd-vhosts.conf` file I have added this Virtualhost
It allows me to use Wildcard names like `testserver1.dev` and `testserver2.dev` I just have to make sure to add the name to my Windows Hosts file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot  E:/Server/htdocs/projects/%1/www
  ServerAlias *.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

What I would like to do though is add to this funtionality and make it work if the name begins with a `www` so `testserver1.dev` would also work as `www.testserver1.dev`

The way it currently is set up, if I tried to access that URL, it would look in a folder called `www.testserver1` instead of the folder `testserver1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the ServerAlias and change the %1 to %-2.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot  E:/Server/htdocs/projects/%-2/www
</VirtualHost>
```

As explained in the [Directory Name Interpolation section of the mod_vhost_alias documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#interpol), the `%-2` will tell Apache to look at the second from the last part of the name.

The next section in the linked document has examples, one of which is the following:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache/vhosts/%-2.0.%-1.0"
```

Which will allow `www.example.com` as well as `www.sub.example.com` or `example.com` to serve files from `/usr/local/apache/vhosts/example.com`. It does this as follows:

```
%-2.0  # The second from the last part of the name with a zero-length substring.
       # The .0 is necessary as we need to specify a literal period next and don't
       # want the parser to confuse it with a substring specification.

.      # a literal period

%-1.0  # the last part of the name with a zero-length substring. The .0 should be
       # optional here as there's nothing left to cause confusion, but it doesn't
       # hurt anything to have it.
```

Comment: Great thanks, I should note I had to keep using `ServerAlias` otherwise it would just route to my servers root